# Scrollbar just disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have made basic menu/ switcher divs, everythnig works great to the moment when I want use JS inside one of them. All divs start on display: none, this parametr destroy my scrollbar in one of the them, scrollbar is just unavailable. If I delete this one (display:none;) switcher works well(I have download huge library with this scroll(that's why I didnt upload this). I don't have any another idea for this menu switcher.

Alternative solution is build this in flesh, but I dont have too much time.

Check this:
[MENU SWITCHER](http://jsbin.com/OsOXEzU/6/)

Comment: Try [jQuery tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Comment: I will try now, but we can't do somethnig with my code?

Comment: Before starting a project you should read the documentation.. You'll be amazed by what jQuery is capable of.

Comment: I'm beginner, that's why when I saw first time jQuery tabs I decide to write it alone. thank you again:)

Comment: Nothing wrong with trying to write something yourself ;) and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you allready load the jQuery.js it seems you are trying to re-invent the wheel.

```
function showhide(obj)
{
    var el = document.getElementById(obj);
    if (el.style.display == 'none') el.style.display = 'block';
    else el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

The function above is the one you wrote. But jQuery has `.hide()` and `.show()`

```
obj = $('.element-class');
obj.hide(); // Will hide the element
obj.show(); // Will show the element again
```

Many things are just a few keystrokes away with jQuery. You should benefit by using it's functions.
Cross-browser support is one of the reasons you should opt for jQuery. You'll end up wasting a lot of time trying to get custom code to work across ALL browsers. (Unless you are a pro)